# Should there be a better explanation on Van Der Waals force?

Tags: physical-chemistry, molecules, intermolecular-forces, dipole, van-der-waals-behavior

The explanation on how Van der Waals force forms is this: Van der Waals forces consist of induced, temporary dipoles between neighbouring molecules. These are caused by constantly shifting electron could, relative to the positions of the nuclei.

I am thinking, since the electron clouds of EVERY atom are constantly shifting, and EVERY atom is constantly induced to a temporary dipole. So there are exactly two factors determine the electron cloud. One is the shifting of the electron cloud itself and the other is due to the induction by other shifting electron clouds. **So should there be a better explanation/description of the Van der Waals force?**

Comment: As you think of the electron cloud as shifting, you should imagine it shifting slightly more this way and slightly less that way, according to the induction by other shifting electron clouds. This is the better explanation you are after.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are London Dispersion Forces generated?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/124094/how-are-london-dispersion-forces-generated)

Comment: This is not just a qualitative explanation, there is actual math/physics behind it. Why do you need “better explanation” if the theory explains well the observations?

Comment: Van der Waals force = London force + Debye force + Keesom force.

Comment: I don't know much about but at least that is an umbrella term/explanation. Mutual back induction is by the way mentioned by book & teachers. Look @Poutnik comment. What is left out at our level, as well as talking of current ring in aromatics, is the nature of the "movement", as for there is no place for it in the quantum description of molecule that we all know. Perhaps I shall think on how to formulate a question here, about this.